# Mail message/attachment is not showing up

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, gmail

I'm using codeigniter to send mail. It works fine but having this weird problem. The mail is delivered to the recipient and it shows the subject. But it won't show the message and attachment.

Here is the code. I think it's a silly mistake I just can't detect. Help me!

```
//configure email settings
    $config = array(
        'protocol'=>'smtp',
        'smtp_host'=> 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port'=>'465',
        'smtp_user'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'smtp_pass'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

    );

    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('xxxxx@gmail.com','myname');
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Test');
    $this->email->message('It works!');

    //attach newsletter to email
    $path=$this->config->item('server root');
    $file=$path . '/codeigniter/attachments/newsletter.txt';
    $this->email->attach($file);

    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo "your email was sent";
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

Comment: Should not new line value be defined in the `$config` array as `'newline' => "\r\n"` ?
Can you see the source of the email received (with Thunderbird for example) and its size to compare to size of attachment + some bytes for the rest of the mail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing set_newline to:

```
$this->email->set_newline("\n");
```

I have had similar issues in the past, and this fixed it for me.